# Handle Google callback response on ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, oauth, react-router

I have a backend Node Express API server which is handling google auth2 through passportjs -> /auth/google to initiate google oauth, and the callback is handled by /auth/google/callback.

On the Google callback route, Node is returning a JWT (res.token).

My question is how do I capture this token on the frontend. On the frontend, the workflow is simply: I have hyperlink to /auth/google. When the user clicks it and gives Google authorisation, he is sent back to the /auth/google/callback route. So, now, how do I capture the res.token header and how do I redirect him to, say, /user/dashboard?r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thoughts, I found the answer myself.

Since (in my case, at least) my Node server is on a different machine than the React frontend application, I definitely cannot use res.send or res.json to send the token from the backend to the frontend. The reason is quite simple actually - /auth/google/callback has to happen on the Node side and therefore the frontend has no access to that route.

So how can we get access to that route? Just use the 'redirect' token technique, by passing it as a parameter, to the address of the frontend (http://frontend.local/?token=jwt). Then on the frontend, just capture that token by using react-router.